# customizing docusaurus search bar v2

Tags: search, documentation, algolia, searchbar, docusaurus

I would like to customize the Algolia search bar in my Docusaurus docs, more specifically, I would like to display the search bar at the top of the sidebar at the left, and not at the top right, which I think it's the default place.

The v2 docs are elusive about it: https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/search/

I found the v1 docs about it, and tried to adapt it to v2 but nothing works:
https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/search#docsNav

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was possible in v1 but no longer in v2. I believe you'll need to swizzle the Navbar component and change it yourself, as the search bar is hardcoded as the rightmost right item:

```html
<div className="navbar__items navbar__items--right">
  {rightItems.map((item, i) =>
  <NavbarItem {...item} key={i} />)} {!disableColorModeSwitch &&
  <Toggle className={styles.displayOnlyInLargeViewport} aria-label="Dark mode toggle" checked={isDarkTheme} onChange={onToggleChange} />}
  <SearchBar handleSearchBarToggle={setIsSearchBarExpanded} isSearchBarExpanded={isSearchBarExpanded} />
</div>
```

The other option might be to make your own navbar search bar and insert it as a new type by swizzling NavBarItem instead or merging your search bar theme somehow. This would let you include it like you would a normal link in the location you want, like you could in v1. I'm not sure if this is actually possible though (I'm waiting for an answer on that topic myself).

Answer (score 0):

You should [Swizzle](https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling) `DocSidebar` Component and render the `SearchBar` component somewhere.